# What will happen if all the population all over the world jumped together at the same time in sea?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, earth

What can happen if a magnitude of such huge force is applied over the sea water of earth?
Force applied will be average mass of each person *7 billion *9.8 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force of humans on the earth is already there before they jump, because people are standing on the earth. With their weight distributed over the entire earth, their jump (which might briefly increase the force by 2-3x) will have no effect. Since you said they would be jumping in the sea, there will be a very small increase in the sea level.

Mass of all the people on earth is approximately $5\times 10^{11}~\text{kg}$; surface area of all the oceans is about $3.5\times 10^{14}~\text{m}^2$, so all of them jumping into the sea at once would raise the average level of the water by about $1.4 \times 10^{-6} ~\text{m}$ or a little over a micron.

Barely a ripple, on the scale of the seas.